# Left Windows/Meta key suddenly stopped working

Tags: arch-linux, kde, keyboard, manjaro, input

Out of nowhere, the left Windows/Meta key on my Corsair K70 RGB MK.2 just stopped working on my Manjaro KDE Plasma system.

The right one still works fine, opening the application launcher as it should.
It also gets recognized by shortcut assignment as the “Meta” key.

The left one, however, doesn’t get recognized by anything anymore. It does send a signal, but in the Application Launcher Configuration it just looks… weird:

[image]
(Note the garbled "name")

And setting it like that still won’t trigger the application launcher. It is as if the keyboard is just sending nonsense on that key all of a sudden.

Apps like https://keyboard-test.space/ or https://www.keyboardtester.com/ don’t recognize it, either, showing either “unrecognized” or nothing at all.

Obviously, I thought maybe the keyboard went kaputt, but I tried two other keyboards and those show the exact same behavior: Right Meta key works fine, left one not at all.
Therefore I strongly suspect something in the system being the cause of this.

It can also not be related to any update, as none were installed in between it working fine and now being broken.

I have no idea how to even debug this problem further, so I'd be thankful for any ideas.

Comment: [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/azgzgj/super_key_not_working_anymore/) says it can be "gaming button" and you have a gaming keyboard

Comment: @Andra thanks, but there is no "gaming button" on a Corsair K70 RGB MK.2... at least I've never heard of that and see no button that would fit the bill.

Comment: three buttons above left?

Comment: Oh, that one. Yes, that does seem to block the Meta key when active, but even when not active, it's still only the right Meta key that works and not the left.
It's all a bit of a mystery.

Comment: For what it's worth: I can confirm this. I have the exact same issue, since (at a guess) about the same time. Same key, same weird symbol, right meta works (I use the meta key + mouse for dragging and resizing my windows, and with the right hand on the mouse, it's annoying the left meta doesn't work). Differences are that I am on Ubuntu 20.04, and I use different keyboards (tested with GMMK Pro and Keychron Q3). So it might be a KDE Plasma keyboard interface issue.

Comment: @9769953 That did the trick for me as well! What an odd thing...
If you post it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Just a small addition, I also had to restart after doing all that to get the left meta key back.

Comment: No restart necessary for me. But if two independent people had this, roughly starting from the same date, and neither of them can't remember having set this option, then my best guess is a misconfiguration in an update of KDE/Kwin or whatever is responsible for this part of KDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me:

Going from Settings:

-> Hardware section: Input Devices
-> Advanced tab
-> Position of Compose key
-> Turn off "Left Win" -> Apply.

It may require a restart.

I can't remember having ever set this option, so possibly it was accidentally set during an update, through a misconfiguration in that update.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had pressed Fn + F9 which entered some kind of "game mode" that disabled the super key

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much. I had this exact same problem and solved it following your advice. The photo you posted so very useful: for me that button has the exact same icon (resembling a joypad I guess), but is located in F2 instead of F9.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this symptom with a similar keyboard (CH-900088-NA) under kde plasma (5.24.5). Seems that the "windows lock key" at the upper right corner has been pressed without me knowing it... Once depressed, meta key (left windows flag) is working as expected again.

Answer (score -1):

Simply restore the defaults in the keyboard layouts.